# is there a way to hide a table column?

Tags: tables, tabularx

Is there a way to designate a specific column in a tabular environment as "hidden" so it is not printed, or not included? Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

By specifying the second l in the tabular env, possibly, as D(elete), I would like to change this

\begin{tabular}{lll}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{tabular}

\noindent to look like this


\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & c \\
d & f
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```